# How do I detect the character encoding of a text

Tags: character-encoding

I have a mySQL database that contains accented characters that are being displayed incorrectly by a HTML page.

The problem is that I do not trust the encoding that the database is reporting for the tables, because the whole thing was migrated from another server that was failing.

I have tried to convert the characters to several encodings but my problem is identifying the source character encoding.

I have copied a segment of text from the database.

This is the phrase as it should have been displayed

> Fóton é uma ferramenta multi-camadas, multi-ní­vel para criar
>   emissores do tipo CAEmitterLayer e partí­culas...

This is how it is being displayed

> FÃŗton ÃŠ uma ferramenta multi-camadas, multi-nÃ­vel para criar
>   emissores do tipo CAEmitterLayer e partÃ­culas...

As I see, this is happening:

- ó is being displayed as Ãŗ
- ú is being displayed as Ãē
- â is being displayed as Ãĸ
- é is being displayed as ÃŠ
- á is being displayed as ÃĄ

Is it possible to identify the encoding by looking at the text?

Comment: HTML/Apache/PHP should be configured accordingly. Is this still on the sequence of a previous question you asked here some while ago? What configurations have you for the default encoding for MySQL/PHP/Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For *simple* text you can use tools like:

- `enca`,
- `file`.

They guess and can verify the encoding of the text.

For MySQL, you can use just simple SQL requests, like it was presented here: [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049958)], [[2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html)].